3 Year Old Son - Only Interested in “Girl” Things
My 2, almost 3, year old son is only interested in “girl” activities and play items. He has an older brother, who had no interest in this type of play so our house is mostly neutral or “boy” toys.
My son loves jewelry, makeup, dresses, hair, princesses, the color pink etc.
For now, I act interested in what he likes and I support him. No shaming in this home.
This isn’t a post to ask what should do, or how to treat him. However, I’m curious, if anyone else has had a similar experience with their child at a young age and if their interests changed or if it stayed the same as an older child. I’ve read that this age is too young to come to any conclusions regarding gender or sexuality but I am curious on real life examples. If you’re comfortable sharing please do. Thank you.

This question is similar to: What is a positive way to handle a boy who acts like a girl?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

seen it a dozen times in kids, it lasts a year or 2 and they grow over it unles youa ctively reinforce this.

Same as A.bakker here; know a neighbor boy during span 2-5y loved all things "girl": pink/flowers/jewelry/etc. (I made him a pink and purple sparkly bracelet.) Now couldn't be more "boy". Don't know why. School? Little sister? No idea.

Thank you for your replies. I’ve had multiple people tell me school will change things. I’m aware I'm jumping the gun worrying about the future as he’s so young. All I want is to support him best and make sure we can avoid bullying or harassment towards him.
As to the other question, I was wondering if anyone experienced this and if they could share how their kid is today. What their personal experience was.

I could have written this myself. My youngest son is the exact same way. He loves dresses, princesses, mermaids, unicorns, jewelry, and Barbie’s. I am at a loss. I don’t know if it’s normal or not. My older son never wanted to be a princess. He only pretends to be female characters in pretend play as well. All his favorite characters are girls. I’m not sure if it’s a phase, but it doesn’t seem like it. He’s 3, and has liked these things since 2. Your son isn’t the only one.

Thank you for your reply. We will be coming up one year of clear “female” interests over here too. The world is crazy today and you can be judged for saying the wrong thing. All I want is the happiest life for my son, so I’m just looking for examples in how others support or navigate through this.

Honestly I’m not sure. We try and redirect with some things. It’s hard to ask questions without being judged by others. I totally get it. I worry most about bullying because of his interests. He’s getting older, and his interests haven’t changed. When we go places he will choose the princess dress, or the pink hat. So far, everyone thinks it’s cute. We only had one issue at a daycare, and the lady said that boys shouldn’t wear dresses or play with Barbie’s. I’m like, he can’t help what he likes. We dress him in clothes from the boys section, but if we go somewhere, he will look at the dresses.
